# integral with complex numbers

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

May I ask how can I calculate the following integral with complex number involved please? Thank you
$\int_0^a \frac{i}{ix + b} dx$, where a and b are two constants.
please note i is the imaginary part. 'i' is not a constant like a and b. Don't ask me to provide i as a fixed number please because it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral of a complex-valued function $f$ over some compact interval $[a,b]$ is defined as

$$\int_a^b f(x)~\mathrm{d}x=\int_a^b \Re(f(x))~\mathrm{d}x+i\int_a^b \Im(f(x))~\mathrm{d}x.$$

In your case you can separate into real and imaginary parts by noticing that

$$\frac{i}{ix+b}=\frac{i(b-ix)}{x^2+b^2}=\frac{x}{x^2+b^2}+i\frac{b}{x^2+b^2}.$$

Thus your integral can be evaluated as

$$\int_0^a \frac{i}{ix+b}~\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^a \frac{x}{x^2+b^2}~\mathrm{d}x+i\int_0^a \frac{b}{x^2+b^2}~\mathrm{d}x.$$

I trust you can take it from here yourself.

Answer (score 0):

By definition an if $f$ is a function with value in $\mathbb{C}$, its integral is defined as $$
\int f(x) dx = \int Re(f(x))dx + i \int Im(f(x))dx
$$
with $Re$ the real part and $Im$ the imaginary part.

So in your case you need to write $\frac{i}{ix+b}$ as $g(x)+ih(x)$ with $g$ and $h$ two real value function, and then integrate it.

Comment: Thanks . I understand what you are saying but I am having trouble for the next .

Comment: Also i as the part of denominator makes it more complex.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it is right :
$\int_0^a \frac{1}{ix + b} d(ix + b) = [ln(ix + b)]|_0^a = ln(ia + b) - ln(b) = ln\frac{ia+b}{b} $.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't see why it is unclear. Could you specify ? What you said doesn't make sense.